# Uvicorn/FastAPI add User-Agent to log message

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I start my app by `uvicorn my_app.app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --proxy-headers`. So I don't use `gunicorn` and can't use its log format https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format

Also, can not find same "format table" for uvicorn.

I create my logger like so:

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

log_config = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
        "access": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
            "fmt": '[%(asctime)s] - %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            "use_colors": False,
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr",
        },
        "access": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "access", "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"},
    },
    "loggers": {
        "my_app": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": "DEBUG"},
        "uvicorn": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": "DEBUG", "propagate": True},
        "uvicorn.access": {"handlers": ["access"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": False},
        "uvicorn.error": {"level": "INFO", "propagate": False},
    },
}
dictConfig(log_config)
logger = logging.getLogger("my_app")
```

The question is: how can I add User-Agent (or any custom variable) to `access` log format? `'[%(asctime)s] - %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s'`

Tried to override `uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter.formatMessage()` here https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/logging.py#L103
but `record` variable does not seem to contain anything similar to request headers.